# UPDATE с инкрементом значений

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Задача пронумеровать строки в БД.
Т.е. я бы делал это так:

```
$lines=mysql_get_lines("SELECT `id` FROM 'table' WHERE `parent`=12");
// И потом на PHP сделал бы цикл:
$i=1;
foreach($lines as $line){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `order`=$i WHERE `id`=".$line['id']);
    $i++;
}
```

Можно ли сделать аналогичную операцию одним запросом к БД?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем одним, всё-таки двумя, но да, можно через пользовательскую переменную:

```
set @i := -1;
update tablename set order = (@i := @i+1 ) where parent=12 order by id;
```